# Web site acessible through Public IP

Tags: .net-framework, asp.net, iis

How can I make my website available to public IP.I am connected to home network using wifi. I will upload web site on IIS 7

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a server on your home computer, you will probably need to set up port forwarding on your router.  This tells your router, which handles all incoming traffic, to send the appropriate external packets to your server computer.

The typical port for HTTP is port 80.  You may find [this](http://portforward.com/) site helpful for configuring your router.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set the bindings correctly on IIS.. (right click the site, edit bindings. Specify the public URL and port no. (80))

Anyway, http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-24678-setting-up-my-own-dns-server should help you out with this.....